# How to make a parallelogram with transform

Tags: css, transform

I want to make this element:

[image: image1]
http://screencast.com/t/T95m22e8OQy

And I know -moz-transform: skew();

```
#parallelogram {
width: 150px;
height: 100px;
-webkit-transform: skew(20deg);
-moz-transform: skew(20deg);
-o-transform: skew(20deg);
-ms-transform: skew(20deg);
background: #FF0000;}
```

for this:

[image: image2]
http://screencast.com/t/HSQ4CLCc

**Update**

**THE SOLUTION:**

```
 transform:         matrix(2.304, 1.020, 0.000, 2.098, 138.441, -46.000);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do a rotation added to the skew, it will give you something like you want :

```
-moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
```

look at this :

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Using_CSS_transforms