# parallelogram menu

Tags: html, css

I've stumbled upon a problem here. I created a menubar which consists several clickable parallelogram menu-items with list and link tags.

Unfortunately, the menubar is showing a problem now. Whenever I try to hover the overlapping part of menu-item, it will automatically choose the next-right menu-item. For example, when I tried to click the pointy part of HOME (which is overlapping with menu-item ABOUT), the menu-item ABOUT would be chosen instead.

I want all of area of each menu-item clickable respectively without any interference from neighboring menu-items. Any helps and suggestions please?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDKNF.png
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnhzt.png

Here's the HTML code:

```
<ul class="header" id="navlist">
    <li id="home"><a href="#"></a></li>
    <li id="about"><a href="#"></a></li>
    <li id="benchmark"><a href="#"></a></li>
    <li id="service"><a href="#"></a></li>
    <li id="work"><a href="#"></a></li>
    <li id="client"><a href="#"></a></li>
    <li id="contact"><a href="#"></a></li>
</ul>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
#navlist {
    position:relative;
}

#navlist li {
    margin:0;padding:0;list-style:none;position:absolute;top:0;
}

#navlist li,
#navlist a {
    height:31px;display:block;
}

#home {
    left:0px;
    width:112px;
    background:URL('../headbar/navmap.png') 0px 0px;
}

#home a:hover {
    background:URL('../headbar/navmap.png') 0px -31px;
}
```

and for another menu-item such as about, client, and others follow the same rule as home.

Comment: Could you please give us example code; otherwise we can't give you a specific answer.

Comment: are you making the clickable area into a parallelogram and not a rectangle?

Comment: I hate to reference w3schools, but... http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_area_coords.asp

Comment: Just the pictures alone are no help, we need to see the code to be able to find where the problem is.

Comment: Sorry for my clumsiness, I've just edited my post.

Comment: @vletech - no, i think neither images nor code are needed here. Parallelograms is enough to know he is expecting a standard box shaped layout to compensate for anti-typical shapes. A hotspot will do it, but if he doesn't want to use those he may need to get extremely tricky with smaller, specifically positioned a tags.

Comment: This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8052804/how-to-make-a-parallelogram-with-transform

Comment: Is this when you click over the very right of the 'home' icon it then selects the 'about us' section?

Comment: yes, @vletech. and for every other menu-item. If I tried to click the very right part of 'about us', the next-right menu-item will be clicked. and so on.

Is it possible for me to avoid the use of imagemap in order to fix that?

Comment: @bfavaretto So, I couldn't use the available images of menu bar and I need to redraw the menu instead?

Comment: Yes, you could do that. But keep in mind it's a bit tricky, and won't work on older browsers.

Comment: @user1971548 No for bfavaretto solution this involves rotating the whole element, including the background image. I would think this would be the only solution to get what you want.

Comment: playing with rotated pseudos to get this form http://jsfiddle.net/P7Zcu/2/

Comment: Splendid, thanks a million guys :D